# Previewing Draft shows white page, publishing works fine?

Tags: pages

I haven't run into this issue before. On my site, if I create a draft of a page and I save the draft and preview it, I get a blank white screen.  However, if I publish that page, it shows up just fine. I'm not sure what could be causing this, but I'm stumped.

I'm using the default page template and not putting any content into the page (it's just a blank page for testing). I enabled wp_debug but nothing showed up there OR in the php error log for this page. Has anyone else had this kind of error?  I assumed that if it was erroring on the draft, it should error out on the published side to, but it's not. Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

You've already tried most of the things I might have suggested, but one more sanity check I'd perform in this situation is just drop an `echo 'test';` into the theme's `index.php` and see if it shows up on the blank preview page. If not, then there's definitely a syntax error someplace preventing code from executing. The other thing to try is to disable all the plugins, and see if the problem persists.